# How to add logo to right hand corner of navbar in flexdashboard?

Tags: r, flexdashboard

I am building a dashboard in R using the `flexdashboard` package (image attached below). I'm looking for a solution to add a logo in the right hand corner of my `nav-bar` in a way that keeps the size of my `nav-bar` unchanged

Here is my YAML

```
---
title: "Inflation & PSCE Outlook"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
---
<style>
.navbar, [data-toggle=tab], .navbar-brand  {   background-color:#75002B;   border-color:black;   color:white; }
</style>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can specify a logo image for your dashboard using the logo option, seen below.

Adding the logo to the right hand side can be done with the following css.

```
---
title: "Inflation & PSCE Outlook"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
    vertical_layout: fill
    logo: path/to/logo.png
---
<style>
.navbar, [data-toggle=tab], .navbar-brand  {   background-color:#75002B;   border-color:black;   color:white; }

.navbar-logo img {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0px;
}
</style>
```